# salesforce api integration through Alamofire?

Tags: swift, salesforce, alamofire, swift4

While integrating for auth api through Alamofire, it gives error.

http://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

```
Optional(["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"])
```

Param: client_id=3MVG9e2mBbZnmM6lFmND2Ju7xFYp.iaixYWQ7tuDZKWs4Jqs9pxjm3kenjwAqhG28yWavIReD9wkchzFaBcMO&client_secret=8967652660758155787&grant_type=password&password=qwerty%4012&username=xxxx%40yahoo.com

Response:

> error = "unsupported_grant_type";
>       "error_description" = "grant type not supported";

I am getting response through POSTMAN so Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't support JSON in the access token request; [the OAuth 2.0 spec mandates application/x-www-form-urlencoded.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)

Comment: The content type is set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"